# Get Frame of Full Page WebView Minus the UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

How do I get the correct frame of a full page webview minus the Navigation Bar.

I tried this

```
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height)];
```

But when I scroll down the scroll bar gets cut off. It looks like the frame height of the webView is still too big.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your navigation bar was added from a navigation controller, you can use:

```
self.view.bounds.size.height
```

However, if you added it yourself in IB or otherwise, use:

```
self.view.bounds.size.height - myNavBar.bounds.size.height
```

...

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```